# Jenkins: Error connecting to a GIT repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I am having trouble connecting to a GIT repository from Jenkins. In my jobs configuration I specified the "Repository" URL" to "xxx@yyy:/usr/data/git/common/ast.git" and get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/data/git-client/bin/git ls-remote -h xxx@yyy:/usr/data/git/common/ast.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

When I run the command "/usr/data/git-client/bin/git ls-remote -h xxx@yyy:/usr/data/git/common/ast.git HEAD" from the shell as the user Jenkins runs as I do not get an error.

What is the problem from Jenkins? How can I find out which directory Jenkins is refering to?

Edit:

I have switched on Jenkins logging for the jenkins-git-plugin but it does not tell me which directory it can not access.

When I start Jenkins as root everything works nicely - so it is definitly a file system access problem - I just do not know which directory git needs access to or how to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. I am not completely sure what fixed it but it maybe that some directoy premissions somewhere under my Jenkins Home directory where screwed up. I did run

```
chown -R jenkins_user:xxx *
```

in the Jenkins Home dir and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the jenkins command locally, you are referring to the branch as HEAD, which works as HEAD is mapped to master branch.

Try specifying the actual branch name in place of HEAD. This is the branch name that you can find in the git repo on github.

Hope this helps..